How to set password rotation policy using Microsoft Graph API or C# SDK
How to set a policy on the tenant so that passwords expire after a given number of days (e.g. 180 days) using either the Graph API or C# SDK?
I can see there is a Graph PowerShell command Update-MgDomain to do this (documented here):

Password expiry duration (Maximum password age) Default value: 90
days. If the tenant was created after 2021, it has no default
expiration value. You can check current policy with Get-MgDomain. The
value is configurable by using the Update-MgDomain cmdlet from the
Microsoft Graph module for PowerShell.

But I can't find the same functionality in Graph API Reference. Is there a way to do this using the API or using C# SDK?

Update-MgDomain cmdlet refers to this endpoint.
For Graph .NET SDK v5, the code should be like this:
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

var requestBody = new Domain
{
    PasswordValidityPeriodInDays = 180
};

var result = await graphClient.Domains["{domain-id}"].PatchAsync(requestBody);


Thanks so much! I tried the same concept using REST API and it worked. This is what I tried:
PATCH /domains/{domain-id} {     "passwordValidityPeriodInDays": 180 }
